# Better scales and Failures of SCH

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, pcf-theory

Assume $\mu$ is a singular cardinal of countable cofinality.  Recall that a scale for $\mu$  consists of an increasing sequence $\vec{\mu}$ of regular cardinals $\langle \mu_n:n<\omega\rangle$ cofinal in $\mu$, and a sequence $\bar{f}=\langle f_\alpha:\alpha<\mu^+\rangle$ of functions in $\prod_{n<\omega}\mu_n$ such that

1. the sequence is increasing modulo the finite ideal, that is,
   $$\alpha<\beta<\mu^+\Longrightarrow |\{n<\omega: f_\beta(n)\leq f_\alpha(n)\rangle\}|<\aleph_0$$
   and
2. the sequence is cofinal in $\prod_{n<\omega}\mu_n$, that is,

$$(\forall g\in\prod_{n<\omega})(\exists\alpha<\mu^+)\bigl[|\{n<\omega: f_\alpha(n)\leq g(n)\}|<\aleph_0\bigr].$$

Shelah has shown that scales always exist, and this question asks about the existence of scales with stronger properties under some additional assumptions.

Definition
Let $(\vec{\mu},\bar{f})$ be a scale for $\mu$ a singular cardinal of countable cofinality.

1. $\bar{f}$ is *good* if for every $\delta<\mu^+$ of uncountable cofinality, there is an unbounded $A\subseteq\delta$ and $n<\omega$ such that the sequence $\langle f_\alpha(i):\alpha\in A\rangle$ is strictly increasing whenever $n\leq i<\omega$.
2. $\bar{f}$ is *better* if for every $\delta<\mu^+$ of uncountable cofinality, there is a closed unbounded $C\subseteq\delta$ of order-type ${\rm cf}(\delta)$ such that for all $\alpha\in C$, there is an $n<\omega$ such that whenever $n\leq i<\omega$ and $\beta\in C\cap\alpha$, we have
   $$f_\beta(i)<f_\alpha(i).$$

(There is, unsurprisingly, a notion of a *very good* scale, which demands a closed unbounded set instead of just an unbounded one in the definition of ``good''.   It is straightforward to see that a better scale is good, and a very good scale is better.)

**Question:** Suppose $\mu$ is singular of countable cofinality, and for any family $\mathcal{P}\subseteq[\mu]^{<\mu}$ of cardinality $\mu^+$, there is a set $X\in[\mu]^{\aleph_0}$ that is not a subset of a member of $\mathcal{P}$.  Is is there a better scale at $\mu$?  What about a good one?

Comments:

1. The additional assumption on $\mu$ says ${\rm cov}(\mu,\mu,\aleph_1, 2)>\mu^+$ for those familiar with Shelah's notation of covering numbers.
2. The answer to this question is ``yes'' if we replace ${\rm cov}(\mu,\mu,\aleph_1, 2)>\mu^+$ by the stronger assumption ${\rm pp}(\mu)>\mu^+$.
3. The assumption that ${\rm cov}(\mu,\mu,\aleph_1, 2)$ is greater than $\mu^+$ implies some of the same combinatorial consequences that are obtained from better scales.  For example, this assumption implies the existence of a sequence of functions $\langle g_\alpha:\alpha<\mu^+\rangle$, each mapping $\omega$ into $\mu$, with the property that for any $A\subseteq\mu^+$ of cardinality $\leq\mu$, we can find finite $s_\alpha\subseteq\omega$ for $\alpha\in A$ such that for $\alpha\neq\beta$ in $A$,
   $$i\in \omega\setminus(s_\alpha\cup s_\beta)\Longrightarrow g_\alpha(i)\neq g_\alpha(\beta),$$
   but this is impossible for $A=\mu^+$.  In Shelah's notation from his *Cardinal Arithmetic*, this says
   $${\rm cov}(\mu,\mu,\aleph_1,2)>\mu^+\Longrightarrow {\rm NPT}_{J^{\rm bd}_\omega}(\mu^+,\aleph_0).$$
   Better scales imply this as you can take $g_\alpha = f_\alpha$. (Also, the conclusion ${\rm NPT}_{J^{\rm bd}_\omega}(\mu^+,\aleph_0)$ is equivalent to the existence of a non-free abelian group of cardinality $\mu^+$, all of whose subgroups of smaller cardinality are free, again by work of Shelah.)
4. The question of whether ${\rm pp}(\mu)>\mu^+$ is equivalent to ${\rm cov}(\mu,\mu,\aleph_1,2)>\mu^+$ when $\mu$ is singular of countable cofinality is a well-known open question.  This equivalence holds for $\mu = \aleph_\omega$, so the answer to my question is ``yes''  in that special case.